# how to convert nsstring to Binary and that Binary to Hexadecimal

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am having multiple values in the string 
Here is the example of my string

```
str1 = @"20AB"

str2 = @"298C30:2FC0A0:2FC09C:FFFFFFFF:2FDFCD34:00"

str3 = @"4ffd565372df51089f2c824526f4f95a13daa867"

str4 = hexa(binary(str1 + str2 +str3))
```

i.e. I need to convert the strings to Binary and then to Hexa decimal and then concat all 3 strings in a single string.

Please help me out how to do so.

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with "convert to binary and then to hexadecimal"? Do you want the string representations of binary and hexadecimal respectively (i.e. 010101... and ff4234...), and why do you want the intermediate "binary" form? Or do you want the raw bytes?

Comment: I am performing some kind of encryption. for that I need such kind of value. so that all strings values can not be easily identified, that's why I need such kind of dual conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much of Obj-C or the iPhone SDK, but in C your solution would be along these lines:

- use `strtol()` to convert the strings into numbers (check the pointer returned through the second parameter to that function for `'\0'` to tell apart whether you reached end-of-string or merely the next `':'` delimiter);
- use `sprintf()` with the `%x` conversion specifier to turn the numbers into a string again.

Unfortunately your question is not precise enough for a more precise answer.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but my simple question is just convert the given string in the binary values and then convert those binary values to Hexa values. and combine all the 3 hexa values to a single formate.

Comment: @iPhone Fun: There is nothing simple about that question, and much guesswork and assumption on our side. Are those colons in `str2` delimiters of seperate values, or should they be ignored? (I assumed they are delimiters.) What the heck do you mean with "binary" values? (I assumed you meant "numerical".) What do you mean with "concat" / "combining" the values? Adding up? Concatenating? What's the required width / delimiter? You want a leading `"0x"` to go with that? You want lowercase [a-f] or uppercase [A-Z]? Or does it not matter? A precise specification of requirements is a skill...

Comment: I am going to perform some authentication with server to register the application user. Mean while I need some data from the user with user's permission for back up and for that I need to create the token. str2 is having delimiters are needed. as well as by creating binary and then it's hexa values will create my token value in small amount. And my server will again decode it by converting hexa to binary to it's original values. and lover and upper does not matter. and concat means I need to have a 1 string which contains all 2 strings hexa values. and also thanks for interest in question.

Comment: @iPhone Fun: This turns into an answer to "how to phrase a good requirement". ;-) It actually does not matter *at all* what you're going to use those strings *for*. You're saying you need "all 2 strings hexa values", but you have *three* strings, and I still have no idea if you need the individual values *concatenated* or *delimiter-separated*. In any which way, the functions I mentioned in my answer can be used to generate *any* result you might wish for. Have you even looked at them, or are you waiting for a readily-written solution in code?

Answer (score 0):

you can use NSScanner for converting to HEx and Bytes to read the binary data...