# How to convert hex to binary?

Tags: objective-c

For Objective-C:

Hi everyone, I'm trying to convert a hex input into binary. For example, someone enters in :

```
A55
```

I want that to convert to

```
101001010101
```

I've tried looking through past posts and none seem to be working for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175833/how-to-convert-nsstring-to-binary-and-that-binary-to-hexadecimal)

Comment: Write your own routine -- it's not hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a built-in function for this. If not, you should at least be able to go hex->dec then dec->bin

You can write the conversion from scratch if you know the number of characters, bin to hex is common enough algorithmically.

- [A mathematical look at the algorithms](http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/~ram/cpsc110/inclass/conversions.html)
- [SO Answers in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819487/efficiently-convert-between-hex-binary-and-decimal-in-c-c) [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483609/how-can-i-convert-hexadecimal-numbers-to-binary-in-c)
- [Base 10 to base n in Objective C](http://blog.callumtaylor.net/convertingfrombase10tobasenobjectivec)
- [C Hex->Bin](http://johnsantic.com/comp/htoi.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use a lookup table: there are only 16 possible characters in a HEX representation, each corresponding to a four-character binary code group. Go through the HEX character-by-character, obtain a lookup, and put it in the resultant `NSString`.

Here is a copy of the lookup table for you.

```
0 0000
1 0001
2 0010
3 0011
4 0100
5 0101
6 0110
7 0111
8 1000
9 1001
A 1010
B 1011
C 1100
D 1101
E 1110
F 1111
```

There are multiple options as to how to do lookups. The simplest way would be making a 128-element array, and placing `NSString`s at the elements corresponding to *codes*  of the characters (i.e. at positions `'0'`, `'1'`, ..., `'E'`, `'F'`, with single quotes; these are very important).

Answer (score 0):

Build a lookup table (an array where you can supply a value between 0 and 15 to get the binary for that hex digit):

```
char *hex_to_bin[] = {
    "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011",
    /* ... */
    "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"
};
```

There should be 16 elements in that table. The conversion process for multiple digits is to handle one digit at a time, appending the results onto the end of your result storage.

Use `getchar()` to read a char:

```
int c = getchar();
if (c < 0) { puts("Error: Invalid input or premature closure."); }
```

Use `strchr()` to determine which array index to retrieve:

```
char *digits = "00112233445566778899AaBbCcDdEeFf";
size_t digit = (strchr(digits, c) - digits) / 2;
```

Look up the corresponding binary values for digit:

```
printf("%s", hex_to_bin[digit]); // You'll want to use strcat here.
```